# "Error in sort.list" when I try to merge tables

Tags: r, merge

I have two tables:

```
> head(entrez1)
          entrez en   affy       
1007_s_at "780"  780  "1007_s_at"
1053_at   "5982" 5982 "1053_at"  
117_at    "3310" 3310 "117_at"   
121_at    "7849" 7849 "121_at"   
1255_g_at "2978" 2978 "1255_g_at"
1294_at   "7318" 7318 "1294_at"  
> head(tf)
             ENSP entrez
1 ENSP00000379387 353274
2 ENSP00000370532   2971
3 ENSP00000355175  22873
4 ENSP00000253008  59335
5 ENSP00000379106   6720
6 ENSP00000291582    326
> z=merge(entrez1,tf,by.x="en",by.y="entrez")
Error in sort.list(bx[m$xi]) : 
  'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

I have tried variations to `merge` them (tried converting `tf$entrez` to string, converting `entrez$entrez` to numeric and merging,calling `as.table`), but neither work, with the same error cropping up

```
Error in sort.list
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: your example works well on my pc, I suspect teh error will be in different types of variables - could you post more information about your data - types of `entrez1` and `tf` and `str()` of both?

Comment: use `dput(sample_data)` to give people reproducible sample data, saves everybody time and increases the likelihood of users helping you out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I rebooted, but still had problems.

Comment: SOLVED, thanks for the suggestions!